# Script to do periodic printing

Tags: shell-script, printing, printer

I have a networked inkjet printer (`HP all-in-one photosmart 5510`), and currently I have a simple script that reminds me periodically to send a small job for printer so that the ink doesn't dry up. I'm using Ubuntu, and printer was added as a network printer from the printers GUI.

I also have a tiny linux box in the network that is always on, and I would like to automate this procedure to a cronjob so that it gets done even I'm not home.

Is there some good way to print an image (jpg) from a bash script ? Also is it possible to query somehow job history from the printer (ie. check when was last printed job, and if it was longer than x days, send a document to print)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF has been the standard printing format for a while. Prepare a PDF file once and for all. You can use the [`convert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/convert.1.html) command from the [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) suite (either the [original](http://packages.ubuntu.com/imagemagick) or the [GraphicsMagick](http://packages.ubuntu.com/graphicsmagick) variant).

```
convert foo.jpg /path/to/foo.pdf
```

You can find printing logs in `/var/log/cups/page_log`. Only the administrator account can read them. Old logs are in files called `/var/log/cups/page_log.0`, `/var/log/cups/page_log.1.gz`, etc. A [log entry](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.7/ref-page_log.html) looks like this:

```
printername 1234 julumme [date] 42 1 - localhost filename.pdf
```

We only care about the printer name and the date here. Log entries will be in chronological order, so we need to grab the last one corresponding to the desired printer. Here's a shell snippet that does this, and compares the date with the current date and prints a file unless something was printed in the last 7 days. Replace `photosmart` by the name you gave to your printer. Warning: untested code.

```
#!/bin/sh
printer_name="photosmart"
last_date=$(
  { zcat /var/log/page_log.1.gz;
    cat /var/log/page_log.0 /var/log/page_log; } 2>/dev/null |
  awk '
      $1 == "photosmart" {sub(/\].*/, ""); sub(/.*\[/, ""); last_date = $0}
      END {print last_date}
  ')
if [ -n "$last_date" ]; then
  seconds_since_last_printing=$(($(date -d "$last_date" +%s) - $(date +%s)))
  if [ $seconds_since_last_printing -lt $((7*24*60*60)) ]; then
    # There was a recent print job
    exit
  fi
fi
lp -d "$printer_name" /path/to/foo.pdf
```

Run this script in a daily (or less frequent) cron job. It will need to run as root because the log files can't be read by ordinary users (unless you change the CUPS configuration).

If you use different printer aliases to print monochrome and color jobs, you'll see the different aliases in the log. However you can use the color alias to print a BW job or vice versa if you pass the option explicitly, so this isn't a reliable test.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was thinking about! I didn't realize `cups` logs are available for this type of parsing. Excellent

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've setup the printer already and your ubuntu box is using `cups`, you may want to take a look into the [Command-Line Printing and Options](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html). Combined with an cronjob, printing an image should be an easy job.